# Why overloaded operator new is considered static

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, static-methods

I came across a situation where there is a need to maintain a count of how many times an object is `allocated` or `copied`. [similar to ref count logic of `std::shared_ptr`]. The object is allocated through `placement new` from a pre-defined memory pool.

NOTE: `std::shared_ptr` is not choosen over a custom solution due to project limitation. So let's not discuss this alternative as a solution to the problem.

But when I try to increment the count, I get the below error :

> invalid use of member 'count' in static member function

Code snippet :

```
void * operator new(size_t size) 
{ 
    cout<< "Overloading new operator with size: " << size << endl; 
    void * p = ::new student(); 
    count++; //error 
    return p; 
}
```

Godbolt link : https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cs7xds

My questions :

1. is overloaded operator `new` considered static by default ?
2. Why the same principle is not applicable to other overloaded operators ?
3. Any reference to details in the c++ standard ?
4. Any other alternate solution to this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What instance would you expect `operator new` to be associated with? It has to be called before the new object can be constructed, so it can't be associated with the soon-to-be instance.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Understood this point. But why compiler does not complain/warn without a `static` keyword in the declaration ?

Comment: Is the member `operator new` called if you use placement new? Those operators just allocate memory which isn't needed for placement new. Seems like you should just track the number of instances using constructors and destructors instead.

Comment: From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new#Class-specific_overloads) : *"The keyword static is optional for these functions: whether used or not, the allocation function is a static member function."*

Comment: The memory allocation function is called "operator new", but it's not really an operator. The only reason it's not called something sensible, like "allocate", is to avoid adding more reserved words. It's also not supposed to create a new object, only allocate memory for one to to be created in.